# VBA Find Not Returning Correct Values When Cells Are Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that is supposed to return one of two text values in column J based on whether or not two adjacent values in that worksheet are found in another worksheet (they MUST be adjacent to each other in both worksheets). If the adjacent values in the one worksheet are found adjacent to each other found in the other worksheet , it returns  "Previously Added," if not, it returns "Tom Added." The code runs, however, if the "SubValueToFind" is a blank value, it may return the wrong text, that is, it may mean to return a "Previously Added," when it actually returns "Tom Added."

Any cell that is classified as "Previously Added" is correct, even if there is a blank cell in the SubValueToFind. However, if that value is blank, which many are, it can mistakenly classify it as "Tom Added," when it should be "Previously Added," as it is in the other worksheet. Again, it only happens when there is a blank value in the Sub column.

```
Sub UpdateTomAdd()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim AcctSearchRange As Range
Dim AcctFindRange As Range, C As Range, Cel As Range, D As Range
Dim AcctValueToFind As Variant
Dim SubValueToFind As Variant
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet, Xfound As Boolean
Dim firstAddress  As String

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentBSCOA")
Set AcctSearchRange = xlSheet.Range("E1:E" & xlSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set AcctFindRange = CurrentSheet.Range("C1:C" & CurrentSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Cel In AcctFindRange.Cells
    Xfound = False
    AcctValueToFind = Cel.Value
    SubValueToFind = Cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
    With AcctSearchRange
        Set C = .Find(AcctValueToFind)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then 'does this mean if the sub value on the new sheet is blank?'
            firstAddress = C.Address
            Do
                If C.Offset(0, 1).Value = SubValueToFind Then
                    Xfound = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Set C = .FindNext(C)
            Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    Cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = IIf(Xfound, "Previously Added", "Added by Tom")
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

If the adjacent values are found to be adjacent to each other in the other worksheet, it should say: "Previously Added."
If the adjacent values are not found to be adjacent to each other in the other worksheet, it should say: "Tom Added."

Blank cells in the Sub column are causing errors.

Comment: Is a formula an option for this? I think you could easily use `COUNTIFS` and an `IF` to get the result you want, if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: To answer the question in your code about `If Not C Is Nothing Then`: If `C` is `Nothing`, it's because the `find` did not find anything, you want to check before doing anything with `C` that it is indeed something (i.e. `Not` Nothing) or errors are likely to occur. This is what your `If` statement does

Comment: @BigBen I am not sure how I would use a formula for this... would you mind explaining a little further?

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(CurrentBSCOA!E:E,C1,CurrentBSCOA!F:F,D1),"Previously Added", "Added by Tom")`  I may have the columns to search switched.

Comment: The formula is returning the same responses as the macro... could it be due to the fact that the cells on the new sheet are not in the same relative spot as the original sheet? @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Set C = .Find(AcctValueToFind)` that will potentially find the cell you are looking for and running the check `If Not C Is Nothing` is good practice but doesn't mean that it found a blank cell. If `C Is Nothing` is TRUE that means it couldn't find a match and therefore won't be referencing any range anywhere, hence being called "Nothing".

A way to check if a cell is blank is `If c.value = "" Then`. So I would nest/modify that statement where it fits appropriately (probably inside the `If Not C Is Nothing Then` block).

Comment: Thank you for your help! what would the "Then" statement look like for that then... I am confused on what to tell the code to do next

Comment: That was an example of a positive look for a blank cell. I should have probably included if you only want to do "stuff" on non-blank cells you can change it to be `If c.value <> "" then` and then have all the code sitting inside that if statement that is supposed to run

Comment: I'm not sure which blank cells are the issue but if I'm reading correctly it's where the test is `If C.Offset(0, 1).Value = SubValueToFind Then`  you could add in an extra condition so it looks like this `If C.Offset(0, 1).Value = SubValueToFind and C.Offset(0,1).value <> "" Then`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Your advice led me to solving the issue.